# Int Variable won't let me add data from UI text field

Tags: ios, swift

I'm currently working on making a savings app in Xcode 10. I'm working on a feature that lets users add the amount of money they have saved for something into the app through a UI text field. I can't find a way to return the text from the text field to an Integer and add that to the total sum of money that has been saved. Also whenever I tried to add a test variable I got plenty of errors.

```
var amountSavedSoFar += amountOfMoneySaved
```

Both I have set to be integers. I'm trying to set amountOfMoneySaved equal to the numbers in the text field, but it doesn't seem to work.

'+=' is not a prefix unary operator
Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'
Type annotation missing in pattern
Unary operator cannot be separated from its operand

Comment: `var amountSavedSoFar` is undefined when you try to add `amountOfMoneySaved` to it - it just doesn't make sense

Comment: Please post code as text, not as a picture.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I do have it defined. Sorry for not posting it with the code. Its
var amountOfMoneySaved = amountSaved.text (Amount saved is my text field)

Comment: @Evan Based on the code you've provided, `amountSavedSoFar` is NOT defined when you attempt to add **itself and something** to it.  You can only "assign" a value when you declare it.  This `var amountSavedSoFar += amountOfMoneySaved` does not make sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a few issues as you mentioned:

1. `amountSavedSoFar` is declared in the `saveAmount` function and will not be persisted if you call that function more than once.
2. `amountSaved.text` is not being converted from String to the appropriate type (Int, Double, etc.)
3. `amountSavedSoFar` isn't typed or initialized.

Try something like:

```
var amountSavedSoFar: Int = 0

@IBAction func saveAmount(_ sender: Any) {
    //Convert the text and default to zero if conversion fails
    amountSavedSoFar += Int(amountSaved.text) ?? 0
}
```

Comment: Seemed to do trick. Will every time the code run will the amountSavedSofar reset back to 0 though?

Comment: No, it will retain its value assuming you're talking about just calling `saveAmount`.